# Блокировка скроллинга страницы при скроллинге дочернего DIV`a?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, прокрутка

Есть чат с фиксированным позиционированием, визуально отображается поверх страницы, мне необходимо заблокировать скроллинг страницы, в тот момент, когда скроллинг внутри чата доходит до верхнего или нижнего предела, сейчас при прокрутке колесиком мыши сообщений чата по достижении начала или конца начинает прокручиваться весь сайт.

Пожалуйста, не предлагайте скрывать скролл-бар:

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
```

Мне необходимо заблокировать скроллинг, когда курсор мыши находится над чатом.

Для наглядности прикладываю скрин чата с сайта:

[image: скриншот чата]

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать и блок с контеном и чат fixed, как-то так:

```css
/*
page-wrapper нужен, чтобы можно было позиционироваться абсолютно относительно page. 
*/

.page-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.page {
  position: relative;
}
.article {
  height: 5000px;
}
.test {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  background: green;
}
.chat {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.chat-content {
  height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="article">article</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="chat">
  <div class="chat-content">chat-content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так внешний же по умолчанию скроллиться не будет, пока скроллится вложенный.

Comment: А как тогда его вообще скроллить?

Comment: Предполагаю никак, но хочу узнать мнение других людей, возможно есть какой-то вариант, хотя я сам склоняюсь что такое реально сделать только с помощью фрейма.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.

Comment: @Johnny, Если никак, то зачем у него вообще скролл?

Comment: @Athari, является. Вопрос "как сделать", ответ "так сделано по умолчанию".

Comment: @Qwertiy Когда я читал вопрос, уже не являлся. :)

Comment: @Athari, мой ответ 42 мин назад, а изменение вопроса - 6 мин назад.

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что речь идет о чате, я это упомянул с самого начала. Прикрепил скрин для наглядности.

Comment: @Athari, я правильно понимаю, что нужно запретить прокрутку основной страницы колёсиком мыши, когда она находится над чатом?

Comment: @Qwertiy Мимо...

Comment: @Athari, да объясни наконец понятно, что требуется.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вы не к тому юзеру обращаетесь. Вероятно, вас интересует Johnny.

Comment: @Athari, да, ошибся что-то.

Comment: @Johnny, ответь пожалуйста на вопрос выше :)

Comment: @Athari да, мне нужно заблокировать прокрутку основной страницы, когда курсор мыши находится над чатом.

Comment: @Qwertiy Обновил шапку вопроса.

Comment: @Johnny Вы с Qwertiy сговорились что ли? :)

Comment: @Athari прошу прощения, я тут впервые задаю вопрос, перепутал автора. :)